# websocket never close, transfer multiple data

Tags: html, websocket

I have builted a web app. I send and receive a lot of data using Websockets and each time I have to open and close a Websocket connection.

Why dont avoid the constant open/close? How about when the page loads, Websockets are created and opened and they never close, so I use the same Websockets to send and receive text, arrays, links, search queries etc. I am even thinking about transfering files like images and/or videos via Websockets.

Can I do this , or do I have to close a WS connection after I am done? Will never-closing WS rise a security issue? Plus I dont know if the WS will actually close when the user leaves the page. If it does not, I guess that is another security issue, right there.

How do I transfer files via WS? I cannot imagine how to do this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Websockets are meant to remain open for the lifetime of the webpage or SPA... it's totally expected normal behavior.

The server might close the websocket at any time and this is also normal behavior - just re-open the websocket.

Normally, servers will only close the websocket if the websocket was idle for a some time (i.e. Heroku set the timeout limit to 50 seconds) or for traffic and concurrency considerations. Otherwise, the websocket connection could remain open for all time.

For example, the [Plezi framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) (Ruby) sends a pong frame automatically every once in a while, so the connection will remain open indefinitely unless the browser closes the socket (usually by exiting the page).